# Why can't the ghc (Haskell) compiler find the module Data.Vector which I have imported? I get the error: Could not find module 'Data.Vector'

Tags: haskell

vector module has been installed by "cabal install vector"

```
bash-3.2$ ghc-pkg list -f $HOME/.cabal/store/ghc-9.2.1/package.db 
/Users/gcolpitts/.cabal/store/ghc-9.2.1/package.db
    primitive-0.7.3.0
     vector-0.12.3.1
```

but the compiler can't find it:

```
$ ghc prob214ff.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prob214ff.hs, prob214ff.o )

prob214ff.hs:14:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Vector’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Functor (from base-4.16.0.0)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
14 | import Data.Vector
```

Thx @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share !

```
 ghc -package-db $HOME/.cabal/store/ghc-9.2.1/package.db  prob214ff.hs
```

solves my problem although it is a regression from previous versions of ghc which didn't require the use of the -package-db option.

I'd love to use GHC_PACKAGE_PATH but I can't see how to make that work. Sec 5.9.5 of the ghc users guide is confusing. It states "A package database is where the details about installed packages are stored. It is a directory, usually called package.conf.d." i.e. not the package.db file that I gave with -package-db on the command line. But where is the package.conf.db directory with info on the vector package that I installed with cabal?

"ghc-pkg list" references /usr/local/lib/ghc-9.2.1/lib/package.conf.d but the output of the command doesn't list the vector package I installed.

"ghc-pkg list -f $HOME/.cabal/store/ghc-9.2.1/package.db"  does list the vector package in it's output but doesn't tell me a package.conf.d directory that knows about the vector package.

Comment: You probably didn't tell ghc where that package.db is. Try `ghc -package-db <file>`, or use `GHC_PACKAGE_PATH`, or use a package environment... See also https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6262

Comment: Thx @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem ! My comment doesn't fit so I changed my question. I guess maybe I should edit the whole thing to ask how to use GHC_PACKAGE_PATH. The fact that I have to use it seems to be a regression but I don't think there's any point in discussing that here. I should just file a bug about that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit fiddly with cabal version 2. Installing packages no longer really makes sense (despite the `cabal install` still existing...). Instead you will probably find it easiest to create a cabal package instead, for example:

```sh
$ mkdir my-package
$ cd my-package 
$ cabal init
<Edit my-package.cabal and add vector to the build-depends line>
<Put the contents of prob214ff.hs in app/Main.hs instead>
$ cabal run
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take your word that the above works but isn't this a regression in cabal? Are there any bugs or documentation about this? I'd be happy to file a bug if you think that makes sense. I've had this problem for a while. It's intermittent and when I've encountered it previously I just deleted everything and started anew but I'm tired of doing that.

Comment: Personally I don't consider it a regression in cabal. The new arrangement with no global package store is more coherent than the old version where package upgrades could break your system. The downside is that running bare `ghc` isn't really a thing any more. Either make a package (as described above) or for a repl run `cabal repl --build-depends vector`, say.

Comment: @GeorgeCo I _kind of_ agree. I still use Cabal v1-style on one of my machines, and though it does occasionally develop the good old _Cabal hell_ symptoms I never found this to be such a bad issue. And I just _like_ the more minimalistic, use-what's-already-there, don't-be-silent-about-reinstalls behaviour. That said: using `ghc` standalone is only making your own life difficult for no good reason. If you have everything in Cabal projects then you can readily build it anywhere, whether with Cabal-v1 or Cabal-v2 or Stack.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in 9.2.2, see https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/20660#note_391573